# flutter: differentiate between widgets that are visual and logical

Tags: flutter

In flutter, everything is a widget. but how dose flutter differentiate between elements that are visual (like button) and elements that are logical (like padding) at the rendering level?

Comment: check this for example: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-renderobjects-flutter/